# How do I make local sites available across home network using MAMP Pro?

Tags: networking, localhost, mamp

I'm using MAMP Pro to create virtual server url's for my local sites I'm developing. I'm having a play with jquerymobile at the moment and have assigned a server name in the "hosts" section of the MAMP admin that is "http://jquerymobile.dev". This works fine on my main machine MAMP is running on but would love to be able to see what I'm doing on my iPhone that is also on my home network.

I can successfully navigate to my computers IP address from my phone and it shows the MAMP homepage, but I want to also be able to navigate to "http://jquerymobile.dev" on my iPhone. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hosts file on other devices in your local network and forward jquerymobile.dev to the local IP address of the machine running MAMP. 
I don't think this is possible on an iPhone though. You might want to try to change DNS zone settings in your router.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Julesj,

In the end I found the easiest way to achieve what I'm after is using https://showoff.io/